# ActionView::Template::Error (Database and Ruby have inconsistent time zone info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

All of the sudden I get the following error in my Rails 5 app:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Database and Ruby have inconsistent time zone info. Database returned 2018-10-31 23:00:00 -0300
```

In my config file I have set the TZ to:

```
config.time_zone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

The database is in UTC. I don't think that I have changed something.
With this error I did not find any similar problems on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your application.rb

> config.time_zone = "America/Sao_Paulo"
>   config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Comment: My DB needs to remain in UTC, Gems like Chartkick need UTC

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the [Groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem, no?  This likely started with the transition from standard to daylight time.

If this is the case, it appears this was resolved in the release of 5.0.0.  See the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

> `Fixed inconsistent time zone info errors around DST with MySQL and PostgreSQL`

Note, it may require you to bump your ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with a [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) query just add the time zone option

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at, time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)").count
```

Match the time_zone option with the time zone stored in the column table